# Azure Pipeline only push NuGet packages that have new version

Tags: azure-devops, nuget, version, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

I have a single repo that contains multiple DLLs which create separate NuGet packages. I would like to use the Azure DevOps pipeline to publish these packages automatically when the master branch changes via the NuGet pack and push tasks. I do not want to change the assembly version of the Dlls/NuGet packages that do not change. Running my pipeline causes an exception because of the duplicate versions.

After reading Microsoft's documentation page, I tried adding publishPackageMetadata=true but the build still fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `nuget.exe push`, we added a `-SkipDuplicates` option in v5.1 and higher: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-push#options

It's also available with `dotnet nuget push --skip-duplicate` in the .NET Core 3.1 SDK and higher: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-push

Taking a 30 second look at the Azure DevOps docs, it looks like they have a "allowPackageConflicts" option: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/nuget?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#publish-your-packages

Comment: Using task DotNetCoreCLI@2 the --skip-duplicate option does not work. There are stackoverflow questions trying to get around this problem. When using task NuGetCommand@2 allowPackageConflicts fixes the issue.

Comment: How do you add these additional parameters to your push command in Azure DevOps Pipeline?

Comment: If using DotNetCoreCLI@2

inputs:
  arguments:  --skip-duplicate